# How do i call async method from a button

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying to call a aysnc method using latest xamrian in alpha using story board designer but i cant seem to call the method from a button click that has been declared by the desginer.
CS

```c#
async public  void Createuser ()
{        
    var user = new ParseUser ()
    {
        Username = txtUserName.Text,
        Password = txtPassword.Text,
        Email = txtEmail.Text
    };

    await user.SignUpAsync ();
}
```

the button which i wish to call the method from is this

```c#
partial void btnSave_TouchUpInside (UIButton sender)
{
    Createuser();        
}
```

But if we look at the following i the designer.cs file

```c#
[Action ("btnSave_TouchUpInside:")]
[GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
partial void btnSave_TouchUpInside (UIButton sender);
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on your question, I assume that you can't just add the async modifier to the event handler as such?

```c#
async partial void btnSave_TouchUpInside (UIButton sender)
{
    await Createuser();        
}
```

I generally do my clicks inline using a lambda:

```c#
btnSave.TouchUpInside += async (sender, e) => 
{
    await Createuser(); 
};
```

Comment: If i do the above first one says the partial modifier can only be immediatly used before class struct interfface or void keyword

Comment: Just swap the words async and partial.

Comment: would u normally do this in viewdidload then i take it

Comment: it says condider changing return type to task im using ios desinger which has its delicare as mentioned abouve

Comment: Yes, I would normally call this in ViewDidLoad.

Comment: @rogue39nin It is very important to ignore the compiler warning asking you to change `async void` to `async Task`. While `async void` is normally terrible practice and harmful, in Xamarin async events, you have to return `async void` or it will fail to compile, with a vague compiler error that does not help you at all in fixing the issue.

Comment: @ChrisMoschini this question was over 5 years ago no need to go back over ur old notifications

Comment: @rogue39nin That is not how StackOverflow works. People google for answers and the current, correct answer is what they're looking for, not historical data. Answers change and rise and fall over time as technology changes.