# F# equivalent of C# async event handler in Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, f#, xamarin.ios

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23659907/how-do-i-call-async-method-from-a-button) shows assigning a button `TouchUpInside` event handler with the following syntax:

```
btnSave.TouchUpInside += async (sender, e) => 
{
    await Createuser(); 
};
```

Is there an equivalent in F#? There does not seem to be a `+=` overload in F#.

I have tried all of the following but the type system always yells at me that the result is not `unit`

```
btnSave.TouchUpInside.Add (fun s e -> async { return () })
btnSave.TouchUpInside.Add (fun s e -> async { return () } |> Async.StartAsTask )
```

The following compiles but throws an expected exception for any actions on the controller because we are no longer on the main UI Thread

```
btnSave.TouchUpInside.Add (fun s e -> async { return () } |> Async.Start)
```

I'd like to be able to run async functions with the F# equivalent of `async/await` without having to constantly marshall back onto the main UI thread similar to the syntac sugar we get in C#